# javac working on server computer but not on client computers for programming purpose

Tags: java

`javac` working on server computer but not on client computers for programming purpose why? Like when I make a program in Notepad and run on server computer in Dos mode its work perfectly, but when I use this on client computer its says:

```
javac is not internal or external command
```

This setup is being used in a school to learn Java programming. I use this path to run a file:

```
E:\java>javac Filename.java
```

this command is work on server computer while rest of other computers does not execute this command.

Comment: Please Show the error message and the related code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. In particular, requests like `please resolve this problem ASAP` usually lead to the question being closed quickly. Also, please take some care on formatting your question.

Comment: In addition to @Andreas' good advice, please do not add your email address asking for private assistance - everything here is done in the open, so that other people may benefit from the answers given.

Comment: I suspect [this question has a few duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javac+is+not+internal+or+external+command).

Answer (score 0):

When you run an executable it needs to be somewhere on your [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable.  Or you can use the full path.  Most likely the client machine doesn't even have the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) installed and thus doesn't have a javac command for you to compile your project.

1. Make sure you have the Java Development Kit installed.  If not, install it.
2. Make sure that the directory containing javac is on your path.  If not, add it (system dependent).

Answer (score 0):

javac.exe is only available in JDK(Java development Kit) not in JRE. I think you have JRE installed on client computers under E:\Java not JDK

Comment: I have installed correct path, JDK is also installed, still the same problem